# React - componentWillReceiveProps doesnt call

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I noticed that componentWillReceiveProps doesnt call when child object of prop is changes . For example when child changes in : this.props.myprop.parent.child , componentWillReceiveProps doesnt fire . What can i do for this problem ? Thanks .

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps(props) is deprecated instead use static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)

Comment: What version of react are you using? Also post some code, without code the answers to your problem will just be guesses.

Comment: @Think-Twice That depends on the version being used. I know in my work place we are still using an older version because we don't want to spend time refactoring stuff right now.

Comment: Agreed. I must have asked for version and then suggested

Comment: @Tyler i use version 55.6 . How can i solve the problem without downgrade ?

Comment: @hamed98 Now I am not familiar with React Native versions; but, I think 55.X is quite a while after reactjs deprecated componentWillReceiveProps (could be wrong, I'm making assumptions). So, I would expect React Native would have updated by now. Again I could be wrong; but, if I am right, this falls back to what @Think-Twice said - use `static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)` instead of `componentWillReceiveProps(props)`

Comment: Ok . Many thanks all